# Input type File excede bytes en PHP

Tags: php, html

Si subo un archivito de audio pequeño (15seg) funciona bien, pero cuando lo hago con una canción (4min) revienta:

```
Warning: POST Content-Length of 9042845 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0
```

En la vista :

```
<h2>Agregar Categoría</h2> 
<hr/>
<div class="container">
    <form action="AgregarCategoria" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {!! csrf_field() !!}
        <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 20px;"> 
            <label for="Nombre Categoría">Nombre Categoría:</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre de la categoría" name="txtcategoria" id='idtxtcategoria' class="form-control" required>
        </div>    
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Imagen Categoría">Imagen/Pictograma:</label><br>
            <input type="file" placeholder="Subir la Imagen" name="fileImg"  id='idfileimg' class="form-control"  accept="image/png, .jpeg, .jpg, image/gif"  required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Audio Categoría">Sonido/Audio:</label><br>
            <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
            <input type="file" placeholder="Audio" name="fileAudio"   id='idfileaudio'  class="form-control"  required accept=".mp3,audio/*">
        </div>    
        <div class="form-group" >
            <label for="colorin">Elige el color de la categoría:</label><br>
            <input name="color" type="color" id="colorin" value=""/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" >    
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btnEnviarCategoria" value="Agregar">
            <input type="button" name="volver" value="Limpiar" onclick="LimpiarDatos();" class="btn btn-primary"><br><br>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<!-- Fin Agregar Categoría -->
```

En el controlador :

```
 public function AgregarCategoria(Request $req) {

    $conexion = new Conexion();

    $NombreCategoria = $req->get('txtcategoria');
    $img = $req->file('fileImg');
    $audio = $req->file('fileAudio');

    $ruta_img = $img->getClientOriginalName();
    $ruta_audio = $audio->getClientOriginalName();

    \Storage::disk('local')->put('categorias/pictogramas/' . $ruta_img, \File::get($img));
    \Storage::disk('local')->put('categorias/audios/' . $ruta_audio, \File::get($audio));

    $color = $req->get('color');

    $conexion->insertar_categoria($NombreCategoria, $this->CarpetaCategoria . $this->CarpetaCategoriaPictograma . $ruta_img, $this->CarpetaCategoria . $this->CarpetaCategoriaAudios . $ruta_audio, $color);

    $this->Cerrar_Conexion($conexion);

    return view('admin/administrador');
}
```

Subirlo, lo sube bien, pero si son archivos pesados, revienta la aplicación ya le he puesto  `<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />` antes del campo file y nada.

Comment: Sin mirar muy profundo, el campo input tiene dos names, eso no puede funcionar.

Comment: pues es verdad, pero entonces qué hago ?

Comment: Aquí tienes toda la documentación: http://php.net/manual/es/features.file-upload.post-method.php pero si tienes alguna pregunta concreta en un momento dado, puedes publicar tu código para intentar resolverlo entre todos. Por ejemplo, en esta no nos muestras como envías los datos o como los procesas, ¿defines bien el form?

Comment: Ya está todo el código, gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### El problema

El mensaje:

> POST Content-Length of XXXXXXX bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608
>   bytes

ocurre cuando se intenta enviar por `POST` un archivo cuyo tamaño excede el tamaño máximo permitido para un archivo que deba ser enviado por `POST`, establecido a 8MB o 8388608 bytes, según el Manual de PHP.

### Solución

Cambiar el valor de `post_max_size` por un valor más grande, pero tomando en cuenta [lo que dice el Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) con respecto al valor que deben tener **otras variables** relacionadas con `post_max_size`:

> **`post_max_size`** define el tamaño máximo de datos de POST permitidos. Esta opción también afecta a la subida de ficheros. Para
>   subir ficheros grandes, **este valor debe ser mayor que
>   `upload_max_filesize`**. Por norma general, **`memory_limit` debe ser
>   mayor que `post_max_size`**. Cuando se usa un integer, el valor del
>   mismo es medido en bytes. También se puede usar la notación reducida,
>   tal como se describe [en esta FAQ](http://php.net/manual/es/faq.using.php#faq.using.shorthandbytes).
>
> Si el tamaño de los datos de POST es mayor que `post_max_size`, las
>   superglobales $`_POST` y `$_FILES` estarán vacías. Esto se puede
>   rastrear de varias maneras, por ejemplo, pasando la variable `$_GET`
>   al script que procesa los datos, esto es, `<form
>   action="edit.php?procesado=1">`, y luego comprobar si la variable
>   `$_GET['procesado']` existe.

### ¿Cómo configurarlo?

Se puede hacer a través de `php.ini` y en algunos casos a través de `.htaccess`. Al menos cuando se hace por `php.ini` es necesario reiniciar el servidor para que los cambios tengan efecto.

### Ejemplo usando `php.ini`:

#### 1.

Convendría que al abrir `php.ini`, busques el valor `post_max_size`, si lo encuentras tan solo cambia el valor que tenga por uno mayor. Si la línea empieza con `;`, borras el `;`.

```
; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
; Its value may be 0 to disable the limit. It is ignored if POST data reading
; is disabled through enable_post_data_reading.
; http://php.net/post-max-size
post_max_size = 64M
```

#### 2.

Como dice la nota del Manual indicada más arriba, verifica que el valor de `upload_max_filesize` no sea mayor que el valor que estableces para `post_max_size`. Deberías tener algo así más o menos en `php.ini`

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 64M
```

#### 3.

Verifica por último que el valor de `memory_limit` no sea menor que el valor establecido para `post_max_size`.  Deberías tener algo así más o menos:

```
; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB)
; http://php.net/memory-limit
memory_limit = 256M
```

#### 4.

Haz una operación `GRI`:) :

- **Guarda** tu `php.ini`,
- **Reinicia** el servidor
- **Intenta** de nuevo subir el archivo...

Debería funcionar.

Comment: Excelente respuesta. @A.Cedano siempre te me adelantas unos minutos xD!

Comment: Lo siento, pero sigue sin funcionar con archivos pesados, FileNotFoundException in Filesystem.php line 40: File does not exist at path . Con los audios cortos SÍ funciona, de todos modos, busco una manera de que NO se puedan subir , no permita el input type file esos archivos pesados, gracias por tu esfuerzo de verdad.

Comment: @EduBw no he entendido bien tu comentario. Ahora bien, si has dado más margen de subida como se indica en la respuesta pero el archivo que intentas subir es más grande que ese margen nuevo que has puesto, es lógico que no funcione. Prueba con un archivo cuyo tamaño sea mayor a 8MB y menor al nuevo margen. Si lo que quieres es limitar el tamaño de fichero que se puede subir ese es otro asunto totalmente distinto del planteamiento original. Este sitio funciona **por preguntas**. Si a raíz de alguna respuesta te das cuenta de que el problema es otro, debes plantear una nueva pregunta.

Answer (score 2):

Par limitar el tamaño de subida de ficheros, puedes usar los mismos casmpos que te suministra el form para determinar el tamaño, estoy hablando en la parte PHP:

```
$audio = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
$type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
```

Luego solo tienes que hacer algo así como:

```
if(($size <= 0) || ($size > 100000 )) {
    // echo "Fichero muy grande"
    exit();
} else {
    // Subir fichero, guardar y demás acciones
}
```