# ¿Cómo resolver este error al usar PHPMAILER? Could not access file

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, mail

Tengo un formulario en **php** y necesito que se envie una foto por correo mediante ***PHPMAILER*** realizada con la cámara del móvil. A veces lo envía correctamente, pero otras me da el error:

> ''Could not access file: ''

Éste es el código para el envio de la foto:

```
$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'],
                     $_FILES['foto']['name']);
```

El input desde la camara del movil es este

```
<input type="file" capture="camera" name="foto" id="foto">
```

`var_dump($_FILES);` da esta informacion. EN ESTE CASO ME HA ENVIADO EL CORREO CON LA FOTO:

```
array(1) { 
            ["foto"]=> array(5) { 
                                    ["name"]=> string(9) "image.jpg" 
                                    ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" 
                                    ["tmp_name"]=> string(27) "C:\Windows\Temp\phpCF0D.tmp" 
                                    ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(978636) } 
        }
```

Ahora no lo ha enviado y el el error de var_dump es este:

```
array(1) { 
            ["foto"]=> array(5) { 
                                    ["name"]=> string(9) "image.jpg" 
                                    ["type"]=> string(0) "" 
                                    ["tmp_name"]=> string(0) "" 
                                    ["error"]=> int(1) 
                                    ["size"]=> int(0) } 
        }
```

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar el input desde el cual mandas el archivo? Parece que no encuentra el archivo en `$_FILES['foto']['tmp_name']`. Pon  también en la pregunta un `var_dump($_FILES);` pulsando en [edit].

Comment: He añadido una imagen del input

Comment: ¿Y el `var_dump($_FILES);`? Por favor pon su resultado en la pregunta pulsando en [edit]. Así podremos ver lo que está llegando realmente. El código es mejor ponerlo en texto siempre, las imágenes son menos prácticas y se dificulta verlas desde dispositivos pequeños.

Comment: Acabo de hacerlo!

Comment: José, toma nota sobre `var_dump` para que lo uses en tus depuraciones, te va ahorrar horas y muchos dolores de cabeza. Se ve claramente en el segundo caso un código de error `1`eso indica que el archivo que intentas mandar en ese caso excede el máximo permitido. Tienes que resolver eso de la mejor manera, hay varias formas de hacerlo: reduciendo el archivo, o cambiando en la configuración del servidor, temporal o definitivamente el máximo tamaño permitido. Te toca a ti decidir que tipo de solución vas a implementar.

Comment: [Aquí hay una respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/142377/29967) que aborda el cambio del tamaño máximo permitido desde la configuración. Léela bien para que decidas si es esto lo que te conviene hacer o no.

Comment: Perfecto, era eso, estaba limitado a 2M. Muchísimas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Para este caso seria bueno ver la ubicación de tu archivo , por lo general simplemente cambiar la ubicación de los mismo o otorgar mayores permisos al directorio podría resolver el problema.

Ejemplo para Linux:

```
$ sudo chmod -R 755 /tudirecotrio.
```

Espero sea de ayuda.

Comment: Lo he probado y sigue igual, tambien lo tengo implantado en un server 2012 con IIS y pasa igual, veces que si funciona y otras el mismo error.