# El nombre temporal de mi archivo no es enviado por HTML, o no es recibido por PHP

Tags: php, html5

Estoy realizando un portal donde se puedan subir artículos científicos. Así es el formulario donde las personas pueden registrar sus artículos:

```js
var nuevo = 1;

function agregarAutores() {

  var campo = '<div id="autor' + nuevo + '"><br><div class="row"><div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="autoresArticulos[]" placeholder="Nombre completo del autor..." required autocomplete="off"></div><div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"><button type="button" class="btn-rojo rippler rippler-default" onclick="eliminarAutor(' + nuevo + ');" style="padding: .4em 1.1em;">-</button></div></div></div>';

  $("#contenedorAutores").append(campo);

  nuevo++;

};

function eliminarAutor(id) {

  $("#autor" + id).remove();

}


$(document).on("keyup", "#formularioArticulo input", function(e) {

  $(this).css('border-color', '#CED4DA');

  var formulario = $(this).parents("#formularioArticulo");

  var input = validarInputs(formulario);

  var select = validarSelect(formulario);

  /*if (input && select) {

    $("#subirArticulo").removeAttr('disabled');

  }else{

    $("#subirArticulo").attr('disabled', 'disabled');

  }*/

});

$(document).on("change", "#formularioArticulo select", function(e) {

  $(this).css('border-color', '#CED4DA');

  var formulario = $(this).parents("#formularioArticulo");

  var input = validarInputs(formulario);

  var select = validarSelect(formulario);

  /*if (input && select) {

    $("#subirArticulo").removeAttr('disabled');

  }else{

    $("#subirArticulo").attr('disabled', 'disabled');

  }*/

});

function validarInputs(objeto) {

  objeto.find("input").each(function() {

    if ($(this).val() <= 0 || $(this).val() == "") {

      $(this).css('border-color', '#EF3109');

    } else {

      return true;

    }

  });

}

function validarSelect(objeto) {

  objeto.find("select").each(function() {

    if ($(this).val() <= 0 || $(this).val() == "") {

      $(this).css('border-color', '#EF3109');

    } else {

      return true;

    }

  });

}
```

```css
#formularioArticulo {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 2px solid #666666;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 3%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form action="../recepcion/recepcionConvocatoria.php" id="formularioArticulo" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">


  <div class="form-group">

    <label for="nombreRegistrador">Nombre completo:</label>

    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombreRegistrador" id="nombreRegistrador" placeholder="Nombre completo de quién registra el artículo..." required="" autocomplete="off">

  </div>


  <div class="form-group">

    <label for="correoRegistrador">Correo electrónico:</label>

    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="correoRegistrador" id="correoRegistrador" placeholder="Correo electrónico de quién registra el artículo..." required="" autocomplete="off">

    <small class="form-text text-muted">El correo electrónico será la primer vía de contacto entre el comité editorial y el Registrador.</small>

  </div>


  <div class="form-group">

    <label for="celularRegistrador">Número de contacto:</label>

    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="celularRegistrador" id="celularRegistrador" placeholder="Número de contacto de quién registra el artículo..." required="" autocomplete="off">

    <small class="form-text text-muted">El número de contacto será una vía alterna de contacto.</small>

  </div>


  <div class="form-group">

    <label for="institucionArticulo">Institución que representa el artículo:</label>

    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="institucionArticulo" id="institucionArticulo" placeholder="Institución que representa el artículo..." required="" autocomplete="off">

    <small class="form-text text-muted">Ingrese el nombre completo de la institución que representa este artículo.</small>

  </div>


  <div class="form-group" id="contenedorAutores">

    <label for="autoresArticulos">Ingresa el nombre de los autores:</label>

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">

        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="autoresArticulos[]" id="autoresArticulos" placeholder="Nombre completo del autor..." required="" autocomplete="off">

      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">

        <button type="button" class="btn-amarillo rippler rippler-default" onclick="agregarAutores();" style="padding: .4em 1.1em;">+</button>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>


  <div class="form-group" id="contenedorAutores">

    <label for="nombreArticulo">Nombre del artículo:</label>

    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombreArticulo" id="nombreArticulo" placeholder="Nombre del artículo..." required="" autocomplete="off">

  </div>


  <div class="form-group">

    <label for="areaArticulo">Área del conocimiento del artículo:</label>

    <select class="form-control" name="areaArticulo" id="areaArticulo">

      <option value="">Selecciona un área de conocimiento</option>


      <option value="1">Agronomía, veterinaria y afines</option>


      <option value="2">Bellas artes</option>


      <option value="3">Ciencias de la educación</option>


      <option value="4">Ciencias de la salud</option>


      <option value="5">Ciencias sociales y humanas</option>


      <option value="6">Economía, administración, contaduría y afines</option>


      <option value="7">Ingeniería, arquitectura, urbanismo y afines</option>


      <option value="8">Matemáticas y ciencias naturales</option>


    </select>

  </div>


  <div class="form-group">

    <label for="documentoArticulo">Ingrese el artículo:</label>

    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="documentoArticulo" id="documentoArticulo" required="">

    <small class="form-text text-muted">El artículo debe tener el <a href="../archivos/plantilla/Guia_Articulo.docx" download="Plantilla formato artículos.docx">formato estipulado</a> en las <a href="../nosotros/" target="_BLANK">instrucciones</a>.</small>

  </div>


  <div class="button-group">

    <button type="submit" id="subirArticulo" name="enviadoArticulo" value="1" class="btn-send rippler rippler-default">Enviar Artículo</button>

  </div>


</form>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Lo envío a un archivo que recibe todos los datos enviados por POST del formulario de arriba:

```
<?php

session_start();

require_once '../modelo/modeloConvocatoria.php';

include '../modelo/conexion.php';

extract($_POST);

if (isset($_POST['enviadoArticulo'])) {

   var_dump($_FILES['documentoArticulo']['tmp_name']);

}

?>
```

Pero esto me devuelve, literalmente: `string(0) ""`

¿Alguien sabe por qué no me recibe el nombre temporal, pero sí el nombre del archivo? Y sobre todo, agradecería si alguien podría ayudarme a resolver ese problema.

Comment: ¿Qué devuelve `var_dump($_FILES)`?

Comment: Me devuelve esto: array(1) { ["documentoArticulo"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(44) "242-Texto del articulo-506-1-10-20160421.pdf" ["type"]=> string(0) "" ["tmp_name"]=> string(0) "" ["error"]=> int(1) ["size"]=> int(0) } }

Comment: Tienes que prestar atención al código de `error 1` en el `var_dump`. Significa que tu archivo no se está subiendo adecuadamente, porque sobrepasa el tamaño máximo permitido. [Revisa la documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/features.file-upload.errors.php). Si te interesa explorar la posibilidad de aumentar el tamaño máximo permitido en subida de archivos [consulta esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/142367/29967) y la respuesta aceptada, donde se explica con detalle cómo hacerlo. OJO a eso, porque se trata de trabajar con el archivo de configuración de PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como dices en tu comentario, `$_FILES['documentoArticulo']['error']` te devuelve el valor `1`. De acuerdo con [el manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/features.file-upload.errors.php) ese valor corresponde a:

> **UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE**
> Valor: 1; El fichero subido excede la directiva upload_max_filesize de php.ini.

Puedes subir el límite del tamaño de subida en la configuración del servidor web, o pedir al usuario que suba un fichero más pequeño.

Comment: Lo subí a 128M y aún así no me permite. Reinicié el xampp y no. El archivo de prueba, pesa 3.80 MB

Comment: ¿Has verificado el cambio observando el valor de `ini_get('upload_max_filesize')` o en la salida de `php_info()`?

Comment: Aún no se modifica. Pero miré directamente en el archivo, y sí está en 128M. ¿Debería reiniciar el PC?

Comment: ¿Estás cambiando el `php.ini` que `phpinfo()` indica como "Loaded Configuration File"?

Comment: Efectivamente, me faltaba reiniciar el PC.