# Error migrar una aplicacion PHP

Tags: php, mysql, apache2, azure

Tengo una aplicación web en php (la hizo el que estaba antes que yo) en local. Me han pedido de migrarla a la nube, básicamente es añadir datos de empresas a la base de datos. En local funciona perfectamente, pero lo he migrado a una VM en azure, le he instalado LAMP y lo que es la página funciona correctamente, se ve y se puede navegar, pero ha perdido la funcionalidad, me explico:
Antes de la migración se podían rellenar los campos de las empresas y se enviaban a la base de datos, pero ahora en azure no, he cambiado el archivo php de la base datos, y lo que es login funciona por lo que puede acceder a la base datos, pero al insertar datos de empresas, me da este error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Delight\FileUpload\Throwable\TotalSizeExceededError in /var/www/html/BotCamara/panel/vendor/delight-im/file-upload/src/AbstractUpload.php:60 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/BotCamara/panel/vendor/delight-im/file-upload/src/AbstractUpload.php(85): Delight\FileUpload\AbstractUpload->withMaximumSizeInBytes(5242880) #1 /var/www/html/BotCamara/panel/requerimentSubmitter.php(90): Delight\FileUpload\AbstractUpload->withMaximumSizeInMegabytes(5) #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/BotCamara/panel/vendor/delight-im/file-upload/src/AbstractUpload.php on line 60
```

Error AbstractUpload.php:60:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Error AbstractUpload.php:85:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Error requerimentSubmitter.php(90):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Parece que el problema ha sido subir el archivo PDF, pero el PDF pesa menos de 5MB que es el límite. Por ultimo he probado a realizar los mismo en la aplicación en local y con el mismo PDF no me ha dado problema al subirlo.

Dejo también el directorio de la app, por si puediera servir de algo, la VM solo tiene apache, mysql y php php-mysql, y lo que es todo el directorio está copiado y pegado de local a la nube por lo que los archivos son los mismo a excepción de la comunicación con la base de datos. Se "ve", pero no "funciona".
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Espero me puedan ayudar.

Un saludo

Comment: El mensaje te está diciendo que intentas subir un archivo que supera el tamaño máximo de subida permitido. Si realmente necesitas subir tal archivo al servidor deberás modificar la configuración de PHP para que te permita subir archivos más grandes. Para más detalles, revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/142377/29967).

Comment: Sí, pero lo que no entiendo es por qué en local si me lo sube y en la nube me da ese problema, cuando el pdf es el mismo

Comment: Porque posiblemente en la *nube* la configuración de PHP sea diferente. La *nube* no es otra cosa que otro servidor, con otro entorno de PHP que no tiene por qué ser el mismo que en local. Por tanto, debes revisar la configuración de `php.ini` en la *nube* y revisar el máximo tamaño permitido y modificarlo, si puedes modificarlo. Eso ya depende del plan contratado que tengas.

Comment: Ha solucionado eso pero me tira este error ahora: ```Excepcion: Delight\FileUpload\Throwable\Error in /var/www/html/Aplicacion/panel/vendor/delight-im/file-upload/src/FileUpload.php:208``` creo que puede ser algo de composer pero no tengo ni idea... Parece que esos archivos estuvieran hechos por defecto

Comment: Convendría ver la traza completa del error. Por cierto, evita poner capturas de pantalla para código y mensaje de error. Es mejor poner el texto, más simple para ti (copiar y pegar) y más simple para los otros usuarios para revisar errores o reproducir el problema en un entorno de prueba cuando esto es posible.

Comment: Este es el error del archivo que me manda: "$targetFile = $this->describeTargetFile($originalExtension);

                if (!@move_uploaded_file($data['tmp_name'], $targetFile->getPath())) {
                        throw new Error();
                }

                return $targetFile;
        }

}
"
He leído algo de comproser pero no tengo ni idea la verdad

Comment: Composer es un manejador de dependencias que te permite por ejemplo instalar con un solo comando determinadas librerías que necesites para un proyecto. [Esta es la página oficial de Composer](https://getcomposer.org/)

Comment: Compara los valores de `post_max_size` y `upload_max_filesize` de los `php.ini` local y de la VM.

Comment: Si en la MV no tengo composer instalado, la librería no funciona?

Comment: No tiene que ver una cosa con la otra. Con Composer puedes agregar una librería completa con un solo comando. Sin Composer tendrías que buscar otra forma de agregar la librería, sea subiendo los archivos manualmente o usando git si la librería estuviese disponible en forma de repositorio. Generalmente Composer viene instalado y si no puedes instalarlo sin problema.